# Why does referencing object property passed in as attribute in angular directive cause error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

See this plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/pj4TwkV7icMp4IdyReZP?p=preview
An object is being passed in as an attribute of the directive.

```
<shape type="person" shirt="blue" dta="{name:'SomeName', age:'21', Hobbies:['reading', 'coding', 'camping'] }"></shape>
```

The properties are then referenced in the template like so `<h1>Age:{{dta.age}}</h1>`

Although it correctly displays the property value, it also causes this error $rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! (see console in plnkr). I understand that the error is caused when the model is 'unstable' - but what is causing the instablity in this case? The values / properties don't change. What is the correct way to achieve the same result without the causing the error?

Answer (score 2):

This error, I think, just tells you that you created in HTML value too long: `{name:'SomeName', age:'21', Hobbies:['reading', 'coding', 'camping'] }`.

It's not good practice (MVC pattern) to put model as HTML attribute.

```
<shape type="person" shirt="blue" dta="{name:'SomeName', age:'21', Hobbies:['reading', 'coding', 'hiking'] }"></shape>
```

I suggest to create `dta` Object in controller:

```
 $scope.dta = {
    name:'SomeName',
    age:'21',
    Hobbies:['reading', 'coding', 'hiking'] 
    };
```

and change `shape` element like:

```
<shape type="person" shirt="blue" dta="dta"></shape>
```

See Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/WdCzf4MhMi3lXp79IH3i?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: +1 and my thanks for the quick reply with fiddle. Yes, passing in the object thru the controller does avoid the error but the cause of the problem does not appear to be the length of the string. I shortened it to only the age property and it still gives the same error.